# Get API Json data in object and array format using redux and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am successful in getting the data from the sample code in the below tutorial with Redux.

https://codepen.io/stowball/post/a-dummy-s-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react

**Below is the format used in the tutorial which works great.**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "List item 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "List item 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "List item 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "label": "label 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "label": "label 5"
    }
]
```

**But I tried several ways and unable to pass the data in the format below**

```
{     
    "banner": [ 
        { "key": "product", "id": "84535", "image_url": "/media/emthemes/slideshow/s/u/sultry-app_12.jpg" }, 
        { "key": "category", "id": "2629", "image_url": "/media/emthemes/slideshow/l/i/limecrime-app.jpg" }, 
        { "key": "product", "id": "84654", "image_url": "/media/emthemes/slideshow/a/m/ameera-app-banner.jpg" } 
    ] 
}
```

**Current Reducer and mapping component in another file :**

```
export function items(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

return (
            <ul>
            {this.props.items.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                {item.id}
              </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        );
```

**Tried with below changes in reducer:**

```
export function items(state = {banner:[]}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you need?

Comment: I need to map and display the data in the below JSON format in my component. 

`{     
    "banner": [ 
        { "key": "product", "id": "84535", "image_url": "/media/emthemes/slideshow/s/u/sultry-app_12.jpg" }, 
        { "key": "category", "id": "2629", "image_url": "/media/emthemes/slideshow/l/i/limecrime-app.jpg" }, 
        { "key": "product", "id": "84654", "image_url": "/media/emthemes/slideshow/a/m/ameera-app-banner.jpg" } 
    ] 
}` 

Please check my edit in question for more details. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change reducer to this:

```
{this.props.items.banner.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                {item.id}
                {item.key}
                {item.image_url}
              </li>
            ))}
```

And change the PropTypes of items in ItemList.js

```
items: PropTypes.object.isRequired
```

I have tried the tutorial and created a working example here:
https://github.com/stackOverflow166/redux-nwb

### Edit2:

#### Cannot read property 'map'

This is problem is about the date type.Add this to the ItemList.js to change the date type to array.Only array has the map function.

```
let bannerArray = []
let banner = this.props.items.banner
for (let key in banner){
     bannerArray.push(banner[key])
}
```

Comment: Hii, Thanks for making the example and replying to my question.  I did as you suggested but i am still getting the mapping error. 

See below error info :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `items` of type `array` supplied to `ItemList`, expected `object`.


Note: I am using react version "react": "^16.6.1"

Importing Proptype like this import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Comment: I believe there is some problem with the latest version of react and redux, because your example works great with the old one. Can you please check with the latest version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1328423 about the map error,I have changed my answer, and about the propTypes error, please share your code about PropTypes.So I can check it.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I just tried with the latest update given by you but it is still not working. Following is the code i have used in Itemlist.js `constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let bannerArray = [];
        let banner = this.props.items.banner
        for (let key in banner) {
            bannerArray.push(banner[key]);
        }
        this.state = { bannerArray };
    }` `
            <ul>
                {this.state.bannerArray.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.key}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        `

Comment: **You can check my full code on this repo [ https://github.com/huzefahusain786/React-Redux ] Kindly help to finish this. I need a robust solution because I may have to use single JSON for multiple components.**

Comment: **Update:**

I was able to render now with the following code, `let bannerArray = [];
        let banner = this.props.items.banner
        for (let key in banner) {
            bannerArray.push(banner[key]);
            return (
                <ul>
                {this.props.items.banner.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.key}<img src={item.image_url} />
                    </li>
                ))}
                {console.log(this.props.items.banner)}
            </ul>
            );
        }`

Comment: now i need your help to know how we can render the data from the same API to another components without having to do componentDidMount in each component. I do not want to hit API in every component.

Comment: @user1328423 get the date in the father component and pass the props down to the children component.

Comment: Can i give API url in the action like this `export function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

        fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5bec1c1a330000cd25fbc245')` and fetch in all the components like this `componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }` ??